# Nginx proxy get each slash part into a variable

Tags: nginx, proxy

how can I get each slash part of the url into a variable to write the proxy URL?

Example:

https://example.com/part1/part2
or
https://example.com/sub/8080

Then

proxy_pass http://$part1.example.com:$part2;

Answer (score 0):

With something like this:

```
location ~* /(.+)/(.+)$ {
    set $hostpart $1;                                                                                            
    set $urlpart $2;                                                                                              

    proxy_pass http://$hostpart.example.com/$urlpart break;
}
```